# angular ui router state being hit but no template returned

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router, ngboilerplate

I'm using ng-boilerplate amd have the following folder structure

```
member
-add
--add.js
--add.tpl.html
-member.js
-member.tpl.html
```

inside add.js I have the following route defined

```
 .config(function config( $stateProvider,USER_ROLES ) {
        $stateProvider.state( 'member.add', {
            url: '/member-add',
            views: {
                "main": {
                    controller: 'AddMemberCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'member/add/add.tpl.html'
                }
            },
            data:{ pageTitle: 'Add member'

            }
        });
    })
```

and inside member.tpl.html i have a link defined to the route

```
<a href ui-sref="member.add" class="btn btn-primary">Add member</a>
```

clicking on the above link changes the url to '#/member/member-add' and changes the page title to match 'Add member' as defined above, but file member/add/add.tpl.html is not loaded in. I can't see any errors in the console and grunt builds it fine, I can see a reference to the file in templates-app.js:

```
angular.module("member/add/add.tpl.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("member/add/add.tpl.html",
    "Add members");
}]);
```

Edit: other routes are fine, its just for routes in a sub-sub-folder i.e app/member/add/

Any ideas why the page is not rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a view named `main` in your page. Something like:

```
<div ui-view="main"></div>
```

Comment: Ah great, but is it possible to "replace" the contents of member.tpl.html rather than adding another <div ui-view="main"></div> to member.tpl.html (I already have one defined in the apps main index.html)

Comment: @IanP, just don't use named views. Specify `controller` and `templateUrl` right in the root of the state definition object. This will cause the default ui-view to have the contents of the template.